# jQuery - load set number of elements with class

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Here is my code:**

```
$loadedContent.load('/test-archive #archive .section');
```

This loads all elemnts with the class of **.section** inside **$loadedContent**.  There are roughly 100 **.section**'s within **#archive**.  My code currently loads in ALL **.section**'s - I want to limit this to call in the first 20 only.

I've googled it but if I'm honest I don't know the right term to google, so I'm struggling to find a solution.

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`:lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) to narrow it down:

```
$loadedContent.load('/test-archive #archive .section:lt(20)');
```